# Как сделать выбор полей в react-admin

Tags: reactjs, frontend, create-react-app

К примеру, есть Datagrid с моей кастомной кнопкой select (это поле я дописываю сам, используя dataProvider):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после выбора пользователя (строки в таблице), соответственно, кнопка должна поменяться на SELECTED (все это хранится локально, запоминается, без запросов)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но тип react-admin не ререндерит изменения, приходится перезагружать
есть ли какие-нибудь решения данной проблемы? как погуглить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге нужно было создать CustomField, и на каждый click делать rerender() - это хук react-admin

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).